# Using same model for two different templates

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a model and I would like to use it with two different templates on the page. I didn't find anything on how to specify what model to use for a template (other than its name).

For example, I would like to display all the subusers from the model "subusers" in the template named "assignationdd". Right now, I already have a template named "subusers" so it links it with the model automatically, but can I reuse the model in another template?

EDIT :

I have a multi-model ressource because I need both all conversations and subusers at the root of the app. I should have precised that before. So there is no change in the url or route, I just want to display my model in 2 different templates. And yes I read the docs on ember-data (and it shows very few and simpler examples).

Router :

```
App.Router.map(function(){

//Routing list to raw namespace path
this.resource('conversations', { path : '/' }, function() {
    this.resource('conversation', { path : '/:conversation_id'});
});

});
```

Route :

```
App.ConversationsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

subusers: null,
currentUser: null,

model: function(params){

        return this.store.find('conversation', { status : params.status});
},

setupController: function(controller, model){

    this.controller.set('content', model);

    if(!this.get('subusers'))
    {
        this.set('subusers', this.store.findAll('subuser'));
    }

    this.controllerFor('subusers').set('content', this.get('subusers'));
},

queryParams: {
    status: {
        refreshModel: true
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the model is assigned by the Route and not the template. You can use one model in multiple routes. I suggest you read the getting started section on Ember and Ember Data.

First of all, don't nest `resource`s. A resource should only be a noun, and a route should be a verb. So your router should be like this:

```
//Routing list to raw namespace path
this.resource('conversations', { path : '/' }, function() {
    this.route('view', { path : '/:conversation_id'});
});
```

Secondly, try this for multiple models:

```
model: function (params) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
        conversation: this.store.find('conversation', { status: params.status}),
        subusers: this.store.findAll('subuser')
    });
}
```

Comment: I added some precisions if it can help you understand my problem. I read the getting started section about 1000 times, but I am integrating ember in a huge app, so I can't use the examples they give because they start from 0 and don't apply to my situation.

Comment: I think you mean that you need to use multiple models in one template, right?

Comment: No actually I need to use it for two templates 'subusers' and 'assignationdd'.

Comment: Well then you can include one of the templates in another. You can use `{{partial}}`, `{{view}}` or `{{outlet}}`. Partial will keep the same context while outlet and view will use a different one. If that doesn’t help you try adding your templates to the question as well.

Comment: You just opened my eyes, I'm gonna try it today and keep you posted. I didn't know about partials keeping the same context (more like I didn't understand it because I read the docs so many times).